# exit app after second back press using toast

Tags: react-native, native-base

This exitAlert is call after android button is press, I want to disable exit after the toast is close, since the toast has no close event, I am using timeout to disable it, obviously the code below does not disable second press exit:

```js
    const exitAlert = () => {
        const duration = 3 * 1000;
          showToast('Press again to exit', duration, 'top');

          BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            BackHandler.exitApp();
          });

          setTimeout(() => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {}), 
          duration);
    }
```

---

Okay this works:

```
let pressTwice = true;
  const duration = 3 * 1000;
  showToast('Confirm exit', duration, 'top');

  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    if (pressTwice) {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    pressTwice = false;
  }, duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```js
componentDidMount(){
   let oncePressed = false;
   const duration = 3 * 1000;
   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
       if(oncePressed){
            oncePressed = false;
            BackHandler.exitApp();
       }else{
            showToast('Press again to exit', duration, 'top');
            oncePressed = true
            setTimeout(() => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
                 oncePressed = true
            }), 
             duration);
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this code ? Answer edited. try now